# Issues with glide bloating images on Android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-glide, android-bitmap

I'm debugging why images are taking vastly more memory than I am expecting them to be, and am wondering if the issue is with something I'm missing with glide.

```
    glide.asBitmap()
            .load(imageUrl)
            .apply(RequestOptions.centerCropTransform())
            .into(object : BitmapImageViewTarget(objectContainer) {
                override fun onResourceReady(resource: Bitmap, transition: Transition<in Bitmap>?) {
                    super.onResourceReady(resource, transition)
                    adapter.setPhoto(resource)

                    var numberOfBytes = resource.byteCount;
```

So the imageUrl if I download the image manually, is just 60126 bytes or 60 KB.

When I print number of bytes after going through this glide load, my image is a whopping 7.6 MB!!!! Its growing by a factor of 100+.

I've noticed that the sizes of any of the images are the same, so I'm wondering if there is some default bitmap buffer size that is massive, that is causing this issue.

Answer (score 1):

When you save an image file on your disk it's usually compressed (JPEG, PNG, and ...) so they usually have small size on your disk.

But when that images go into memory (what glide does when it loads that images file) it goes all crazy and consumes all memory it needs because it's not compressed anymore, its RAW image that your working within your memory.

So a lossless compression format like JPEG can make the file size 500kb but when you load that image it can go for example to 10 MB on device memory.